# Read File to Process Stdin ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

How do I pipe a file into the stdin of a process using ProcessBuilder?  The program I am reading the stream from is written in C, but I do not know anything else about it.

Here is the relevant java:

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./program").inheritIO();
  Process p = pb.start();
  DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("./my-file.txt"));
  byte[] dinBytes = new byte[din.available()];
  din.readFully(dinBytes);
  din.close();
  OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
  os.write(dinBytes);
  os.close();
  int rc = p.waitFor();
  System.out.println("RC: " + rc);
```

Which returns the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:434)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
$ input in flex scanner failed
```

Comment: Is the file really a data file or a text file? The `.txt` suffix seems to imply text, but you are reading it as a `DataInputStream`. Why?

Comment: @RealSkeptic the file will always be an ascii text file. I wasn't aware it made any difference using a DataInputStream. As far as I know they can all read ascii.

Comment: Javadoc: "A data input stream lets an application read primitive Java data types". That's not for reading text files.

Comment: You say "pipe a file *into* the stdin of a process", but then you say "The program I am reading the stream *from* is written in C". Are you sending data *to* a program, or receiving data *from* a program?

Comment: @Andreas I want to send data to a program.  I want to replicate "./program < my-file.txt" on Linux, ideally.  Also, what would you recommend for reading text files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause for your error is the call to `.inheritIO()` when you build the process. This causes all the process's standard file descriptors to be inherited from the Java process. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) says:

> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form
>
> ```
> pb.inheritIO()
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
> pb.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT)   
>   .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
>   .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)
> ```

And the documentation for `redirectInput(Redirect)` says:

> If the source is `Redirect.PIPE` (the initial value), then the standard input of a subprocess can be written to using the output stream returned by `Process.getOutputStream()`. If the source is set to any other value, then `Process.getOutputStream()` will return a null output stream.

So, basically, the default is that there is a pipeline between the Java process and the built process, so that you can push in data from your program to the process. But you released the standard input of the process from the pipe and let it wait for input from the user console, but then you tried to treat it as if it's still part of the pipe, and get your end of the pipe in order to push data inside. You get a null output stream, and as soon as you try to put something in it, you get an exception.

So you shouldn't make that call. And since you want input from a text file, the easiest thing to do would actually be to redirect that input stream to the file directly. Again, redirecting breaks the pipe - but you won't need it because the redirection actually does what you need:

```
// Take input from a file, output and error go to user console
pb = new ProcessBuilder("./program")
         .redirectInput(new File("./my-file.txt"))
         .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
         .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

An alternative method, in case you want to pipe in more than one file, is to keep the pipe to the process standard input around, but copy the files using `Files`:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("./program")
         .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
         .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
Files.copy( Paths.get("./my-file-1.txt"), os );
Files.copy( Paths.get("./my-file-2.txt"), os );
// more files

os.close();
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

---

Regarding the `DataInputStream`: it is a type of `InputStream` used for processing binary data that was written from a `DataOutputStream` - with ints, doubles etc. written in binary form. Of course, like any `InputStream`, you can read bytes from it as-is. But for that, you don't really need to wrap it in a `DataInputStream`.